# How to test using StepVerifier a Flux<String> coming from a Controller using WebTestClient in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, webtestclient, stepverifier

In Kotlin, I tried to test a simple @RestController using StepVerifier.

```
  @GetMapping("/helloInt")
  fun helloInt(): Flux<Int> {
    return Flux.range(1, 3).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300))
  }
```

The test is here:

```
@Test
  fun callingIntEndpoint(){
    var responseBody = webTestClient
      .get()
      .uri("/helloInt")
      .exchange().returnResult<Int>()
    StepVerifier
      .create(responseBody.getResponseBody())
      .expectSubscription()
      .expectNext(1)
      .expectNext(2)
      .expectNext(3)
      .verifyComplete()
  }
```

And it works just fine.
However, when I tried to test a `Flux<String>`

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
  fun hello(): Flux<String> {
    return Flux.just("testing", "hello", "Kotlin")
      .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300)) //to make sure they are 3 distinct messages
  }
```

This Unit Test does NOT fail, and it shows clearly what the problem is:

```
@Test
  fun callingTheEndpoint() {
    webTestClient
      .get()
      .uri("/hello")
      .exchange()
      .returnResult<String>()
      .responseBody
      .test()
      .expectNextMatches { it.equals("testinghelloKotlin") } // but this is NOT what I actually would want to see
      .verifyComplete()
  }
```

Why is it that the 3 strings are concatenated?
When I open the URL in a browser I clearly see the 3 string one by one.

I would like to make this UT work:

```
@Test
  fun callingTheEndpoint() {
    webTestClient
      .get()
      .uri("/hello")
      .exchange()
      .returnResult<String>()
      .responseBody
      .test()
      .expectNextMatches { it.equals("testing") }
      .expectNextMatches { it.equals("hello") }
      .expectNextMatches { it.equals("Kotlin") }
      .verifyComplete()  }
```

Comment: It is not clear what content-type is used for your test. Do you want your endpoint to send plain text or json ? If you want json, a flux of String should be transformed to an array of string, I think. Try to force the "Accept" header to "application:json" on your webtestclient to check that ?

Comment: @amanin you are absolutely correct.  it is missing a response content type
`@GetMapping("/hello", produces = ["text/event-stream"])` solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

adding `produces = ["text/event-stream"]` does the trick

```
@GetMapping("/hello", produces = ["text/event-stream"])
  fun hello(): Flux<String> {
    return Flux.just("testing", "hello", "Kotlin")
      .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(300)) //to make sure they are 3 distinct messages
  }
```